# jQuery kick out of focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

simple Question I think. I got an input field which is focused on load via jQuery.

```
$('#myInput').focus();
```

What I want is when you klick on the arrow keys, go out of the input and so that you can scroll with the keys down.

```
if (e.keyCode === 37 || e.keyCode === 38 || e.keyCode === 39 || e.keyCode === 40 ) {
     return false;
}
```

return false is to prevent rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.blur()` to lose focus

```
$('#myinput').blur();
```